# iOS App crashes at end of for loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-loop

I'm pretty new to Objective C, and I've been having quite the roadblock in my code...
I am making a (very) simple card game to run on iOS. All you are supposed to do is draw cards until a Joker is drawn, then the game ends.
My app has been crashing at a curly bracket at the end of a for loop that is making card objects to put into the array

Here's my Deck.m:

```
#import "Deck.h"
#import "Card.h"
@implementation Deck
@synthesize deckArray;

- (void)removeCard {
    [deckArray removeObjectAtIndex:deckArray.count];
}

- (void)generate {
    NSLog(@"Generating deck...");
    NSMutableArray *deckArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
        //Make a card
        Card *card = [[Card alloc]init];
        //Give it some values
        card.value = i + 1;
        card.suit = @"Hearts";
        //Put card in array
        [deckArray addObject:card];
        NSLog(@"Added object (%@) to array",card);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
        //Make a card
        Card *card = [[Card alloc]init];
        //Give it some values
        card.value = i + 1;
        card.suit = @"Spades";
        //Put card in array
        [deckArray addObject:card];
        NSLog(@"Added object (%@) to array",card);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
        //Make a card
        Card *card = [[Card alloc]init];
        //Give it some values
        card.value = i + 1;
        card.suit = @"Diamonds";
        //Put card in array
        [deckArray addObject:card];
        NSLog(@"Added object (%@) to array",card);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
        //Make a card
        Card *card = [[Card alloc]init];
        //Give it some values
        card.value = i + 1;
        card.suit = @"Clubs";
        //Put card in array
        [deckArray addObject:card];
        NSLog(@"Added object (%@) to array",card);
    }  //Crashes on this line: Thread 1: Breakpoint 2.1
NSLog(@"Generated deck");
}

- (Card *)topCard {
    return [deckArray objectAtIndex:deckArray.count];
}
@end
```

I'm pretty sure it is the most obvious thing in the world but, again, I am pretty new on programming in general

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't see anything wrong there, but elsewhere...  `[deckArray removeObjectAtIndex:deckArray.count];` that will always crash your app.  The array is 0 based, so there is no object at `deckArray.count`.  You need to subtract 1.

Comment: Are you sure that it's a crash and not just an active breakpoint?

Comment: what I'm seeing here, is local `deckArray` will hide the global one...

Comment: Crash Log will explain everything, why app crashed. Pls post Crash log

Answer (score 0):

I can see issue in tow methods: removeCard and topCard.
You try access object which is out of bounds:

```
[deckArray objectAtIndex:deckArray.count]
```

If you have 5 items in the array deckArray.count returns 5 but last index is 4 (arrays index are zero based) so you have to replace call to deckArray.count to deckArray.count-1.

```
- (Card *)topCard {
    return [deckArray objectAtIndex:deckArray.count-1];
}
```

And do the same in removeCard method.

Comment: Hm....I tried both of these things. To fix the 'out of bounds' by just making a topCard object in my ViewController.m as shown: and I fixed the count problem, but yet the exact same thing happens...

Comment: `Card *topCard = [deck.deckArray objectAtIndex:deck.deckArray.count - 1];`

Comment: Can you post the crash log?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of communicating...I've been really busy for the last couple days. There WAS a set breakpoint in the code...that was an accident. Now there is a crash log:

Comment: 2014-06-25 11:36:11.320 Joker Bomb[26719:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM removeObjectAtIndex:]: index 56 beyond bounds [0 .. 55]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010194a495 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001016a999e objc_exception_throw + 43
 2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001018f0906 -

Comment: [__NSArrayM removeObjectAtIndex:] + 438
 3   Joker Bomb                          0x00000001000017bf -[Deck removeCard] + 95
 4   Joker Bomb                          0x0000000100001ed0 -[ViewController drawCard:] + 560
 5   UIKit                               0x0000000100257f06 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 80
 6   UIKit                               0x0000000100257eb4 -

Comment: [UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 17
 7   UIKit                               0x0000000100334880 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 203
 8   UIKit                               0x0000000100333dc0 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 530
 9   UIKit                               0x000000010028ed05 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 701
 10  UIKit                               0x000000010028f6e4 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 925
 11  UIKit                               0x000000010026729a -

Comment: [UIApplication sendEvent:] + 211
 12  UIKit                               0x0000000100254aed _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 9579
 13  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001018d9d21 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
 14  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001018d95f2 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 242
 15  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001018f546f __CFRunLoopRun + 767
 16  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001018f4d83 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
 17  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000103ac1f04

Comment: GSEventRunModal + 161
 18  UIKit                               0x0000000100256e33 UIApplicationMain + 1010
 19  Joker Bomb                          0x0000000100002903 main + 115
 20  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000101fe25fd start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: In the bottom of my answer I said that you have to make the chance in removeCard method as well. Change it to [deckArray removeObjectAtIndex:deckArray.count-1]; and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

This line : `NSMutableArray *deckArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];`

You already declared deckArray in your header file(.h).
You should do: `deckArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

Answer (score 0):

As told in the Crash log, I had my 'remove card' method take away an object that didn't exist because arrays are zero-based. Also, I put `self.` in front of `deckArray` seemed to help. I should've learned a bit more Obj-C before posting this question, so my apologies to you. `.count - 1` also helped on the other methods.